# Remmina VNC - Cursor Disappears when using "grab all keyboard events"

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, cursor, remmina

I am using Remmina (1.4.21 installed via SNAP) on Ubuntu (20.04.3 LTS) to remote into a mac computer, using VNC plugin for GNOME & KVM; everything works great when I am not using the "grab all keyboard events" option. However, when I use "grab all keyboard events" (which I would like to use), the mouse/cursor immediately disappears.

It is of note that I am also using Remmina RDP protocol to access a windows machine, and do not have this issue when using same features (grab all keyboard events).

Is there some option that needs to be enabled on my mac? Or any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if Wayland is enabled, if it is false, please enable it.

It seems that on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS upgrade from 20.04 it disabled Wayland and reverted to x11.

1. We will edit the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file

`sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

2. Within this file, look for the line that says #WaylandEnable=false.

`WaylandEnable=true`

3. Restart GDM3 or reboot

`sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

WARNING: you will be logged out, so you need to login
i can confirm this method as for me it worked

Reference:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Please give me reputation that i am able to start also commenting :)

Thank you for your time reading